# Multidimensional Array Validation and Insertion

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been searching and banging my head since 2 days to achieve what I want to achieve, but since google and other source could not solve my issues, am posting it here. I have a form where I submit array and post it via PHP to insert it into mysql database.

Form values

```
<tr class="alternate-1">
<td>1</td>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description-1" type="text" value="test1"></td>
<td><input name="amount[]" id="amount-1" type="text" value="500.00"></td>
<td><input name="paidby[]" id="paidby-1" type="text" value="">Company</td>
<td><input name="paidto[]" id="paidto-1" type="text" value="client"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alternate-2">
<td>2</td>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description-2" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="amount[]" id="amount-2" type="text" value="400.00"></td>
<td><input name="paidby[]" id="paidby-2" type="text" value="">Company</td>
<td><input name="paidto[]" id="paidto-2" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alternate-3">
<td>3</td>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description-3" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="amount[]" id="amount-3" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidby[]" id="paidby-3" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidto[]" id="paidto-3" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alternate-4">
<td>4</td>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description-4" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="amount[]" id="amount-4" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidby[]" id="paidby-4" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidto[]" id="paidto-4" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alternate-5">
<td>5</td>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description-5" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="amount[]" id="amount-5" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidby[]" id="paidby-5" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input name="paidto[]" id="paidto-5" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

If you see the first row contains all required values. And on second row, only amount is entered and `description` field and `paidto` field is not entered. Hence, I do not want to process the form and should throw an error.

My php code is like this

```
if($_POST['sform'] == "1")
{
    foreach($_POST['description'] as $key => $desc)
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['description'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['amount'][$key]) || !empty($_POST['paidto'][$key]))
        {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO `expenses` (`amount`, `description`, `paidby`, `paidto`,) VALUES ('.$conn->qstr($_POST['amount'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['description'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['paidby'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['paidto'][$key]).')';
            $results = $conn->Execute($query);
        }
        else
        {
            $error = "Form contain errors, please fix";
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, it throws an error as well as it inserts first 2 rows data.

Where as it should not get inserted as second row `description` and `paidby` values are missing. How can I validate properly and insert only correct data to database.

Kindly help...

Comment: have you ran a var_dump on the global ($_GET/$_POST) what was submitted?

Comment: Yes, you want me to post it here?

Comment: it would help, then I can tell you the path of each [var1][var2][var3]..., for a couple so you can see how to do it.

Comment: so every row of data is required?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what it is programmed to do. You have a loop that checks each set of input. If the input exists, your code says to insert into the database right away. You need to move the query out of the for each loop and check for errors first. I highly recommend checking all values in JavaScript before they are posted to the actual server.

Comment: @Ghost Only if they enter next row. Part of the data should not get through...

Comment: @EarleDavies I want to make sure from server side, then I will work on js later.

Comment: @sammry then just use `&&` and operator on all of it

Comment: @Ghost I have tested that too, it does not work, second row part data gets inserted.

Comment: @eyeLoveFiddle please find it here,  http://codepad.org/NeeSgOwt

Comment: Why wasn't the var_dump broken into lines for ease of read?

Comment: His issue doesn't seem to be the lack of data, there is clearly data coming through. He wants it to not insert into the database if the user does not enter values into ALL fields.

Comment: If you want to use your current code then wrap your foreach loop in a _transaction_. You _rollback_ if any error or _commit_ if all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Comment with code is too long so i'll post an answer in hopes it helps you. The quickest / easiest way I see to do it would be to loop through the data twice. Once to verify it's not blank, and once to actually insert the data...

```
$error = '';
foreach($_POST['description'] as $key => $desc){
    if (empty($_POST['description'][$key]) || empty($_POST['amount'][$key]) || empty($_POST['paidto'][$key])) {
      $error = "Form contain errors, please fix";
      break; // this stops it from going through every input. if one fails, they all fail
    }
}

if ($error != ''){
    foreach($_POST['description'] as $key => $desc){
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `expenses` (`amount`, `description`, `paidby`, `paidto`,) VALUES ('.$conn->qstr($_POST['amount'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['description'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['paidby'][$key]).', '.$conn->qstr($_POST['paidto'][$key]).')';
        $results = $conn->Execute($query);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried with `&&` too, first row is still getting inserted. throws error too but not inserting second row part data.